# ContentProvider starting service before Junit tests in test enviornment

Tags: android, android-service, android-contentprovider, android-testing

I have a whole bunch of existing tests for an `aidl service`. The test class extends `ServiceTestCase`. They were all working fine until I recently added a new `ContentProvider` in the same package. Now when I run the tests one or two of the existing tests fail randomly.

The reason for this fail is that I am binding to the service from `onCreate()` of the `ContentProvider`. When the test framework restarts the process the `ContentProvider` is getting created automatically and it starts the `aidl service` **BEFORE** the test has executed `setup`. This results in the service being running even when I have not started it from the particular test. This causes timing issues which cause the random test to fail.

I tried out following things :

1. If I comment out the `bind` call from the `onCreate` of the new `ContentProvider` then all tests still pass successfully.
   (Note : None of the existing tests needs this provider - I still need to add the tests for this provider)
2. I tried setting some boolean from tests and checking that in onCreate() of the provider - but that does not work since provider is initialized before the `setUp()` of the junit test
3. If I add `startservice()` in tests that did not call it previously then the service actually gets started 2 times and I can see 2 instances running during the unit test